# New core module paths in node.js

Tags: node.js

Struggling to search for this online. New versions of nodejs have core modules like:

```
require('node:assert') /// vs require('assert')
```

and

```
require('node:net')    /// vs require('net')
```

I cannot find out what this means vs the original core module paths. Is there an explanation for this change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a module supports being imported with a prefix and without a prefix, it functions identically no matter how it's imported.

For built-in modules that have already existed - like `fs` - the old way of `require('fs')` will continue to work. But some new experimental modules are prefix-only; to import them, you must prefix them with `node:`. [If you don't](https://fusebit.io/blog/node-18-prefix-only-modules/?utm_source=www.reddit.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=none):

> `'node:test'` is the first core module that can only be imported using the `'node:'` prefix. In order to use Node's new test runner, you must `import 'node:test'`. If the `'node:'` prefix is not included, Node.js will attempt to load a module named test from userland instead.

Why prefixes? From the same link:

> As previously mentioned, the explicit distinction between Node core modules and userland modules is the biggest benefit of prefix-only modules. For the Node.js core project, this change also makes it significantly easier to introduce new modules. Because core modules take precedence over userland modules during module loading, introducing a new core module has historically been treated as a breaking change and sometimes involved reaching out to npm module authors to negotiate the use of a module name. Prefix-only core modules provide a clear delineation between core and userland, reducing much of the friction involved in adding a new core module.
>
> Using `'node:'` as a namespacing mechanism also allows new core modules to be introduced with more appealing names. For example, the new test runner was able to claim the name `'test'` instead of something longer like `'test_runner'` because there was no chance of a naming conflict.